# Backing up 200TB of data from networkshare to multiple 8TB external HDDs (Linux)

Tags: linux, usb, backup, external-hard-drive, smb

I'm working for a company which collects tons of sensor-data from test drives. Currently we have about 200TB (1,638,400 Gbit) of data that needs to be backed up.

We're planning to set up a tape library at the end of the year, but for now we must copy the data onto multiple HDDs formatted with ext4.

A server with a 10Gbit/s connection to the sensor-data is available for the backup. This Server has two UBS 3.0 ports. The server currently has debian installed, but we could install any linux for this task.

Our externals HDDs are Western Digital MyBooks 3.0 with 8TB of storage, and have a write speed of 180MB/s (1,440Mbit/s).

So with two USB 3.0 ports we are theoretically able to write 2.8Gbit/s, which leads to a total write time of approximately 162 hours (6.8 Days). With this being the optimal case and does not take into account the time to swap the drives, we are expecting it to take at least two weeks with five work days each. Please correct me if I'm wrong.

While this situation screams TAPE LIBRARY! We have to go the UBS 3.0 way for now.

I would love to hear your suggestions on how to solve this problem in the fastest and easiest way.

Any help is much appreciated! Thank you!

Comment: Welcome to Super User Caetno! What specifically would you like an answer to? It seems like you already have a solution in place until your tape library is set up.

Comment: To reduce the data volume you could consider data compression. It might make sense to connect the disk drives to the USB ports ahead of time to avoid manual swapping delays.

Comment: Hey bertieb! I find the soloution with the 26 HDDs very unelegant. I was hoping for some hints at software I could use to make this process less aweful.

@Axel Kemper
I'll have to talk to my manager again to check if compression is an option.

Comment: Create a split tar with 8 TB each? The disks won't get faster so you're stuck with that time anyway? It's going to be interesting to see how you manage changes to the dataset you're creating a backup of with such a big time frame.

Comment: The changes to the dataset will be updated every two weeks. But the HDDs will be put into a safe for the next months. The backup in this form, will be done 2 times this year.

Comment: Does the data realistically break into smaller parts? e.g: per customer / sensor / location / day / etc...

Comment: Am I correct in thinking that this is *backup* solution? (rather than an online solution). If so, have you considered a snapshotting filesystem to handle incremental backups?

Comment: What is your current storage solution (where the data currently resides)? Is there any particular reason not to re-produce this elsewhere? Again - snapshotting filesystems like ZFS come to mind to efficiently handle incremental updates to your data. I would do careful research before assuming that a "_tape library_" is the correct answer.

Comment: Incremental  backups are not a option here. We just make a full-backup of a snapshot. The next backup would be in a couple of months. The data currently resides on an Dell Isilon. The server with the external USB drives is in the same room as the Isilon. I can't say anything about the data structure, because I do not have access to it yet.

Comment: I would suggest forgetting about USB and just getting an eSATA docking bay and a bunch of regular SATA disks.  It will be faster and cheaper than the USB, and SMART health monitoring doesn't usually work with USB.

Comment: 1) Not sure you can add the bandwidth of the two USB ports, better check that out first 2) all this may also depend on the available bandwidth on the Isilon (how many nodes...)  3) you can add more servers (even with only Gigabit interfaces) and have one or two disks per server (only one if just a Gigabit). Maybe there is a way to add disks to the Isilon, and have the data copied to them and then remove the disks. Did you ask your Isilon support?

Comment: Whats the hold up on the tape library?  It seems tapes would be more cost effective in a from scratch endevour and be the fastest form to backup.  Also, we use WinRAR to help split archives, create recovery records, make file checksums, etc all in one fell swoop; even if we do not use it for compression.

Comment: Find a way to implement incremental or differential backups in your cold backups?  That is I am assuming most of the 200TB is old data and only a small amount is new?